# Parsing JSON, browser sees it as an array of strings, not an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

very noob Javascript question I suppose.
I'm building a demo where I'm parsing some SQL output from an API and would like to present this on a website. However, I'm struggling to parse the output and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I've got this in my `index.html.js`:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() { 
        return {
            stocks: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getStocks() {
            try {
                const apiUrl = `${getAPIBaseUrl()}/api/getStocks`;
                const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
                app.stocks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error(ex);
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getStocks();
    }
});
```

In my `index.html` I have this here:

```html
<div id="app" class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Stocks</h1>
        <div id="stocks">
            <div v-for="stock in stocks" class="stock">
                <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                    <div class="list-item" :key="stock.price">
                        <div class="lead">{{ stock.id }}: ${{ stock.price }}</div>
                    </div>
                </transition>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, `stock.id` and `stock.price` don't seem to get parsed. `stock` seems to just be a string, not a JSON object.
Debugging the app I can see the following as my data.

`Array(5) [ "{\"id\": \"amzn\", \"price\": 1785.6600341796875, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"msft\", \"price\": 138.42999267578125, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"googl\", \"price\": 1244.280029296875, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"ba\", \"price\": 331.05999755859375, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"air.pa\", \"price\": 122, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}" ]`

So the browser sees it as an array, but rather an array of strings it seems, not an array of JSON objects.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: `response.data` is JSON, you should just use `app.stocks = JSON.parse(response.data)`

Comment: That's just what I ended up with in all my tests and what got me "closest" to what I thought could work.

Comment: Am I seeing your screenshot right, that it's an actual JS array of stringified objects?

Comment: So if I only use `JSON.parse(response.data)` then I receive the following error:
`SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 76 of the JSON data"`

Comment: But, this got me on the right track. Thanks. `app.stocks = JSON.parse('['+response.data+']');` this fixed it.

Comment: So the issue was *response.data*, which wasn't included in the OP. Perhaps you can write an answer and accept it, otherwise you might as well delete the question.

Comment: double check that your JSON response is properly formed. axios' default response is JSON, so you shouldn't even need JSON.parse

Comment: @RobG apologies, it seems like @rob edited my question and removed the image of `response.data` that I had included in my OP as what the browser saw it as.
I will edit my OP and also write an answer.

Comment: @DavidO'Brien—Ok, but you should have included a minimal example of *response.data* as text, not an image (e.g. `'"{\"id\": \"amzn\", \"price\": 1785.6600341796875}", "{\"id\": \"msft\", \"price\": 138.42999267578125}"'`). Not everyone can see images and it makes the task of replicating your issue harder. As far as possible, you should post a minimal example in the question that replicates the issue, preferably as a runnable snippet. Then we have everything we need to give you a good answer in a short time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to understand where exactly you have to do the modification and what little mistake you did has already been pointed out in the above comments.

```
> var arr = [ "{\"id\": \"amzn\", \"price\": 1785.6600341796875, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"msft\", \"price\": 138.42999267578125, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"googl\", \"price\": 1244.280029296875, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"ba\", \"price\": 331.05999755859375, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}", "{\"id\": \"air.pa\", \"price\": 122, \"_attachments\": \"attachments/\"}" ]
undefined
> 
> item0 = arr[0]
'{"id": "amzn", "price": 1785.6600341796875, "_attachments": "attachments/"}'
> 
> item0Obj = JSON.parse(item0)
{ id: 'amzn', price: 1785.6600341796875, _attachments: 'attachments/' }
> 
> item0Obj.id
'amzn'
> item0Obj.price
1785.6600341796875
> item0Obj._attachments
'attachments/'
>
```

And finally, let's do it for all.

```
> // Do it for all
undefined
> newArr = arr.map((str) => JSON.parse(str))
[
  {
    id: 'amzn',
    price: 1785.6600341796875,
    _attachments: 'attachments/'
  },
  {
    id: 'msft',
    price: 138.42999267578125,
    _attachments: 'attachments/'
  },
  {
    id: 'googl',
    price: 1244.280029296875,
    _attachments: 'attachments/'
  },
  { id: 'ba', price: 331.05999755859375, _attachments: 'attachments/' },
  { id: 'air.pa', price: 122, _attachments: 'attachments/' }
]
>
```

After that you will have an access to inner elements of array.

```
> // List out all prices
undefined
> for(let obj of newArr) {
... console.log(obj.price) // obj["price"] can also be used here
... }
1785.6600341796875
138.42999267578125
1244.280029296875
331.05999755859375
122
undefined
> 
> for(let obj of newArr) {
... console.log(obj["price"]) // obj.price can also be used here
... }
1785.6600341796875
138.42999267578125
1244.280029296875
331.05999755859375
122
undefined
>
```

So just check the `response.data` and its type using `console.log(response.data, typeof response.data)` and take below decisions.

If

- `response.data` is  something like `["{\"k\": \"v\"}", "\"k2\": \"v2\""]` as you are printing then you have to use `app.stocks = response.data.map((obj) => JSON.parse(obj))`.
- `response.data` is something like `[{"k": "v"}, {"k2": "v2"}]` then you just need to use `app.stocks = response.data` (as it's already a list of objects).
- `response.data` is something like `'[{"k": "v"}, "k2": "v2"]'` (string) as you are printing then you have to use `app.stocks = JSON.parse(response.data)`.

Take your decisions properly and think about your `response.data`, its type may be `'object'` | `'string'`. And use `JSON.parse()` to get object form, if any of your list item is in string form.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the JSON I received from the server seems to be malformed.
`app.stocks = JSON.parse('['+response.data+']');` 
fixed this.